# My first random password generator

Tags: beginner, c

I'm making a simple program that generates a random password of some length with or without special characters, just for the sake of learning the C language. Finally I've got this working very well based on the outputs below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


char *generate_random_password(int password_lenght, int has_special_characters)
{
    const char *letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const char *digits = "0123456789";
    const char *special_characters = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";

    char *random_password = malloc(sizeof(char) * (password_lenght+1));

    srandom(time(NULL));

    if(has_special_characters)
    {
        char to_be_used[95] = "\0";

        strcat(to_be_used, letters);
        strcat(to_be_used, digits);
        strcat(to_be_used, special_characters);

        for(int i = 0; i < password_lenght; i++)
        {
            const int random_index = random() % strlen(to_be_used);
            const char random_character = to_be_used[random_index];

            random_password[i] = random_character;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        char to_be_used[63] = "\0";

        strcat(to_be_used, letters);
        strcat(to_be_used, digits);

        for(int i = 0; i < password_lenght; i++)
        {
            const int random_index = random() % strlen(to_be_used);
            const char random_character = to_be_used[random_index];

            random_password[i] = random_character;
        }
    }

        return random_password;

        free(random_password);
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", generate_random_password(17, 1));
    printf("%s\n", generate_random_password(17, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
|ZzN>^5}8:i-P8197

vPrbfzBEGzmSdaPPP
```

It's working!

But I'm completely in doubt about these strings, pointers, char arrays, etc. I have no idea if this is written "the right way" or how it could be better. I'm concerned if I allocated the right amount for each string/char array, and if it can break or crash in some future.

PS: I'm new at C programming, that's why I don't know much about pointers and memory management yet.

If can anyone give me some feedback about it I will be very grateful!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, maverick. Your code is currently not platform independent due to the use of `srandom` and `random`. If this is intended, please [edit] your post to include your target and host programming platform, as reviewers can add platform dependent notes. You might also add relevant tags. If you intended to create platform independent code, feel free to also [edit] your post to indicate this.

Comment: @Mast: this version does have some of the bug fixes pointed out in SO comments.  (e.g. `to_be_used` is now initialized before the first `strcat` reads it.  I would have used `strcpy` instead of zeroing that local on the stack and then using strcat.  Or really I would have [done what @Baldrickk suggests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229927/my-first-random-password-generator/230026#230026) and not done any copying).  But anyway, this is a repost with some of the bugs fixed.  I guess still a crosspost but I was wondering why nobody was mentioning the things from the SO comments)

Comment: I know you're doing it only for excercise, but see [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/32019) on security stack.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I see a double-backslash \\ inside the double quoted string, so there's a backslash in the character literal.  Or were you typing a space as special char?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I swear I checked it three times before posting. But it doesn't seem to have been edited, so I must have lost my mind

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Typo

`lenght` is spelled `length`.

### Magic numbers

What does `95` signify? You'll want to put this in a named `#define` or a `const`.

### Allocation failure

After calling `malloc`, always check that you've been given a non-null pointer. Allocation failure does happen in real life.

### Indentation

You'll want to run this through an autoformatter, because your `if` block has wonky indentation and needs more columns to the right.

### Inaccessible statement

```
    return random_password;

    free(random_password);
```

This `free` will never be called; delete it.

### `Random`

The larger conceptual problem with this program is that it uses a very cryptographically weak pseudorandom number generator. This is a large and fairly complex topic, so you'll need to do some reading, but asking for random data from an entropy-controlled system source will already be better than using C `rand`.

That aside: you aren't calling `rand`, you're calling [`random`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random):

> The random() function uses a nonlinear additive feedback random number generator employing a default table of size 31 long integers to return successive pseudo-random numbers in the range from 0 to RAND_MAX. The period of this random number generator is very large, approximately 16 * ((2^31) - 1).

It's probably not appropriate for cryptographic purposes. Have a read through this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c/39475626#39475626

Comment: Thank you for the accept, but I suggest that you instead unaccept, upvote, and wait a while for other suggestions to come in for other users before you decide on an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will write the Allocation Failure test for the malloc().
About the free(), I read that after using malloc() to manual allocate some memory, I also need to manualy free the memory after using it. I put free() after the return because when I put it before, the string "random_password" was returned empty, I don't know why, maybe the free() before "deleted" the variable in some way.
The random() function is Linux only.

Comment: `return` terminates the function, so nothing after it will be run. But you're correct to identify that, in general, allocated memory should be `free`d. In this case, it would be the responsibility of `main` to do that.

Comment: Agreed that the C library `rand` function is cryptographically weak, but this isn't cryptography. Even knowing the exact random algorithm used it wouldn't help you crack the password, particularly as you don't know any of it. Taking the remainder of the generated number mod the length of the character set would further obfusticate things. Knowing nothing more, you would still have to run through all RAND_MAX possibilities.

Comment: @PeterJennings Key and password generation are *absolutely* activities requiring cryptographic strength. Given that password generation requires a tiny amount of data and only needs to occur once, the marginal added cost and complexity are more than worth it - even if it brings password attacks from "infeasible" to "extremely infeasible".

Comment: @PeterJennings  The `srandom` function is initialized with the return from `time`.  If we know the year the password is generated, there are fewer than 32 million possible passwords.  You are also wrong about the "knowing the exact random algorithm won't help you crack the password" - there are many, *many* passwords that using `random` cannot generate even if the initial seed is adequate.

Comment: There's also the age old `random() % <some random number >` error.

Comment: @Peter There've been successful real-world attacks on people using a weak crytographic RNG that was initialized based on the current time (even when they added the PID to it). What Martin is talking about is an absolutely practical attack.

Comment: Using srandom(time(NULL)) is clearly the limiting bug; if used server-side, it opens the barn door for attackers to ask for a password reset and try just a handful of options before succeeding. Client or server-side, it means instantly pwning a new sign-up. A better source of entropy, even if you don't resort to OS/hardware sources, is clearly preferred, but using rand alone isn't a problem given the huge range of rand mapped to a tiny range of symbols, unless the lib implementation of rand is *horribly* broken. The point of a password generator is just reasonable entropy, not maximum.

Comment: Given that the program is intended "just for the sake of learning the C language", I wouldn't focus too much on the entropy issue.  But yeah, definitely choose a better RNG seed than `time(NULL)` if you intend to actually use the program to generate passwords.

Comment: @SilverbackNet Huge range of rand? Rand_Max is only guaranteed to give 32767 unique values which is trivial to hack. The whole function specification is horribly broken, don't blame implementations that don't want to change a broken function just to marginally improve security.

Comment: I guess I've used gcc too long, I didn't realize VC still defines it as 32767.

Answer (score 11):

Whilst your code works, there are a number of simplifications that you might try.

1. As Reinderien says, get rid of "magic" numbers
2. Having done that, declare a single string containing all 95 characters with the special ones last. This does away with all the `strcat` code.
3. It's good practice to declare `has_special_characters` as type `bool`.   You will have to include `<stdbool.h>`.
4. You can then test it to set an integer variable, `modulus_divider`, to the correct `const` or `#define` value as in 1).
5. You can then take the modulus of the random number with `modulus_divider` That way you don't need to keep using `strlen(to_be_used)` and you only need one generating loop.
6. You don't really need all the intermediate variables in your `for` loop. Assuming you have set up `char_set` as the full 94 character array as in 2), your entire `for` loop could become:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < password_lenght; i++)
   {
       random_password[i] = char_set[random() % modulus_divider];
   }
   ```

---

Later

I'm not claiming this is perfect, but here is my version. I don't currently have a C compiler installed but this does compile and run with the online compiler at [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *generate_random_password(const int password_length, bool has_special_characters)
{
    const int alphamerics = 64; /* length of alphameric character set */
    const int alphamerics_plus = 94; /* length of alphameric character set plus special chatacters */
    const char character_set[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"; /* full character set */
    int n =  has_special_characters ? alphamerics_plus : alphamerics; /* set the length of character_set to be used */

    char *random_password = malloc(sizeof(char) * (password_length + 1)); /* allocate memory for password */

    srandom(time(NULL)); /* initialise random number generator, srandom(clock()); works just as well*/
    for (int i = 0; i < password_length; i++)
    {
        random_password[i] = character_set[random() % n]; /* get a character from character_set indexed by the remainder when random() os divided by n */
    }
    random_password[password_length] = '\0'; /* append terminating null to string */

    return random_password;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", generate_random_password(17, true));
    printf("%s\n", generate_random_password(17, false));

    return 0;
}
```

Typical output is

```
W$Mg-tT?oTwa~EF$S
xGLMrqJBS6IB96xvp
```

Comment: Instead of commenting the description of a variable, why not use descriptive names? The compiler does not care if the varaible has a long name like `alphanumerics_plus_special_characters` or `length_of_characters_to_be_used`.

Comment: @dustytrash It's a matter of personal preference to some extent. Long variable names are a double edged weapon. Yes they are descriptive, but they can become unwieldy and make lines of code excessively long and awkward to read. My take is to use fairly short but descriptive names and expand on their use in the comments to allay any doubt. As for comments, I'm old school. I've been writing C on and off for over 35 years (Kernighan and Ritchie was my text book) and have always adhered to the idea of commenting most important lines to aid the next guy who needs to edit the code.

Comment: @dustytrash I admit that 'n' instead of 'length_of_characters_to_be_used' was a slip of the pen! It should, at least , have been a bit more descriptive. Another reason I've been liberal with the comments is to help the OP, an learner, understand the code.

Comment: The suggested code leaks memory

Comment: @MooingDuck I never said it was perfect. I like some variation on Ronald's idea of declaring the memory in the calling function (main) and passing a pointer. That should fix it. If this were some full blown password generator you would take user input for the password length, malloc the memory, call this function and free up the memory in the calling function once you have used the password,

Answer (score 7):

You could get away without all the complicated memory allocation if you simply require that the calling code passes you the memory for the password. It could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void generate_password(char *password, size_t password_size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < password_size - 1; i++) {
        password[i] = alphabet[rnd_int(alphabet_len)];
    }
    password[password_size - 1] = '\0';
}
```

The `char *` means "a pointer to a character". In C, a pointer to a character can also mean "a pointer to a character and some memory beyond". This is commonly used to refer to strings. The `char *` then points to the first character of the string, and the string continues until it reaches the character `'\0'`, which is binary 0. Not to be confused with the character `'0'`, which is the digit zero.

Of course, the variables `alphabet` and `alphabet_len` are undeclared in the above code. Same as the `rnd_int` function that generates a random number from the range `[0, n)`.

The code would be called like this:

```c
int main(void) {
    char password[80];

    generate_password(password, sizeof password);
    fprintf("password: %s\n", password);
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent point; creating a contract where one doesn't need to exist is a bad idea. Expect callers always forget and leak memory, or worse use the wrong kind of free, even if you tell them to call deallocate_password(). That said, for security reasons requiring a call to wipe the password from memory might be necessary.

Comment: Do you mean "without" in the first line?

Answer (score 5):

It's been touched on (e.g. fixed in Peter's example) but not explicitly stated by anyone - but to me, the most obvious issue is in the duplication of code.

You have the following `if` statement:

```
if(has_special_characters)
{
  //codeblock 1
}
else
{
  //codeblock 2
}
```

where `codeblock 1` and `codeblock 2` are almost exactly identical.  In fact it seems that the only difference is that you have this line in `codeblock 1`:

```
strcat(to_be_used, special_characters);
```

You can completely remove the duplication of code and wrap only that line in an `if` block.

Although, I'd also suggest using Peter's second point, and not using strcat at all.  You can put all the characters into one string from the start and use the `if` to determine the range which you will cover:

```
//adjacent strings are concatenated by the compiler
const char* characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                         "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                         "0123456789"
                         "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
const unsigned int alphanumerics_len = 62;
const unsigned int all_character_len = 96;

int char_range_max;
if (has_special_characters)
{
  char_range_max = all_character_len;
} 
else
{
  char_range_max = alphanumerics_len;
}

//...intermediate code

const int random_index = random() % char_range_max;

//...more code
```

We can then improve upon this further by having the compiler handle the string lengths for us with a little pre-processor use to prevent anything needing repeating:

```
#define AN "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"\
           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"\
           "0123456789"
#define SP "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
const int alphanumerics_len = sizeof (AN);
const int all_character_len = sizeof (AN SP);
const char* characters = AN SP;
```

I'd personally also prefer to replace the verbose if-block with the more concise:

```
const int char_range_max = has_special_characters ? all_character_len : alphanumerics_len;
```

which also has the advantage that it can be defined as const too.

Comment: Too bad C doesn't make it easy to put labels part way through a string so you could have the compiler calculate `alphanumerics_len` for you.  That would be easy in assembly language: just put a label after those bytes, and another label at the end of the string, so you can do `end1-start` or `end2-start` instead of hardcoding either length.  (You could have used an array so you could at least use `sizeof` for `all_character_len` though.)

Comment: If you put the special chars *first*, you could use `strchr(characters, 'a')` to find a new start position (and a smart compiler could optimize that to pointer += constant).  But choosing just a different length with the same start is most efficient.  I guess you could `strrchr` at runtime if you wanted to avoid hardcoding lengths that match the string contents.  Or `memrchr` if you use an array so total length is a compile-time constant.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can use sizeof (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022113/4022608) but only to find the maximum length, so you would need to have a hard-coded value regardless...  There is probably something a little more inventive that can do it, but would possibly impact readability, or memory use.  I can think of a readable alternative using the preprocessor, but it would rely on the compiler optimising out the creation of unused arrays, which is a little dirty.

Comment: That's what I said: you can use `sizeof` for `all_character_len` but not `alphanumerics_len`.  Good idea though; with macros you could concat everything for the actual definition, or just the alphanumeric part for `sizeof("abcdefg...")` as a compile-time-constant integer.  Yes that works: https://godbolt.org/z/ikLz_3  I thought I was going to have to cast it to an anonymous array or something.  (Just using a string literal as an operand to `sizeof` doesn't make it part of your program so it doesn't even need to be "optimized away")  Oh, another answer on the Q you linked points that out.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/T8-gm_ demonstrates this working in the context of this question :)  @PeterCordes worth editing into the answer do you think?

Comment: Yes, I'd put that in.  Hard-coding a length requires updating 2 things if you ever add another special character, so it's highly frowned-upon and usually only justifiable for performance reasons.  An answer that recommends hard-coding lengths / magic numbers isn't very good for coding-style.  Since macros allow us to get just as efficient machine code without hard-coding lengths, we should use that.  (And as a bonus, it's no worse to read than a runtime `strcat` + `strlen`).  Your method (selecting a different length) is clearly more elegant and doesn't offend the reader's sense of efficiency.